# Authentication of Passport.js is failing at server

Tags: node.js, express, next.js, passport.js

I have working on my school project
I have 2 different domains
-https://greensweep.in/ (backend deployed built in express)
-https://www.punjabvacancies.live/  (frontend in next js)

Both are deployed on the different one on the digitalocean and another on the vercel

I am using passport package for the authentication purposes with google auh. I am just storing the cookies in the backend
like this

```
app.use(
    cookiesSession({
        name: "session",
        keys: ["googleAuth"],
        maxAge: 10 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // cookies are stored for 10 days
        sameSite: "none", // Allow cross-site access
        secure: true, // On
    })
);
```

and I just send the request from my frontend using axios withCredentials:true which helps me to authenticate in the backend
These things work file till I am on the localhost as they are at same place.
Buy now my frontend is not able to send the cookies to the backend.

How can i correct it.

here is the code how i made the axios request

```
 axios.get(BaseURL + "api/v1/auth", { withCredentials: true })
            .then((res) => {
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    setuserData(res.data.user);
                    setuserState("authenticated");
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                setuserData([]);
                setuserState("unauthenticated");
            });

        return () => {};
```

and here is the code of cors

```
var allowedOrigins = [
    "https://www.punjabvacancies.live",
    "http://www.punjabvacancies.live",
    "https://punjabvacancies.live",
    "http://localhost:3000",
];

app.use(express.json());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "https://www.punjabvacancies.live"
    ); // Update with your allowed origin(s)
    res.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
    ); // Update with your allowed headers
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    // Add other necessary headers
    next();
});

app.use(
    cors({
        origin: function (origin, callback) {
            if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
                callback(null, true);
            } else {
                callback(new Error("Not allowed by CORS"));
            }
        },
        optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
        credentials: true,
    })
);
```

Image of localhost where cookies work fine
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The cookies part shown in this image is always missing from the time i moved to the production
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0agAO.png